# Better alignment for enumitem list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, lengths, enumitem

In the following screenshot, the alignment of the 2nd `A)` and the space between the label of the 2nd list and the fraction have been obtained empirically n: see `\hspace*{1.375em}` and `label*={\Alph*)\,\,}`. You can see some shifts in the following screenshot.

**My method is not good.** I would like to use one better approach based on the settings of the standard vertical list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{parskip}

    \makeatletter
        \newlist{@inlinechoices}{enumerate*}{1}
        \setlist[@inlinechoices]{label*={\Alph*)\,\,},itemjoin={\qquad},labelindent=5em}
        \newenvironment{inlinechoices}{\hspace*{1.375em}\begin{@inlinechoices}}{\end{@inlinechoices}}
    \makeatother

    \newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[choices]{label*={\Alph*)},leftmargin=3em}
    \newcommand{\choice}{\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Which fractions are reduced ?

    \begin{choices}
        \choice $\dfrac{4}{7}$
    \end{choices}

    \item Which fractions are reduced ?

    \begin{inlinechoices}
        \choice $\dfrac{4}{7}$
    \end{inlinechoices}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List spacing parameters are quite complicated.  Here at least is one that is a little less hacky, and allows you to set the value in the `choices` list to match the `\hspace` value in the `inlinechoices` environment. To make the labels identical, I've created a new alignment scheme called `straight` which simply sets the label with a following `\quad`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip} % for zero par indent the right way

\SetLabelAlign{straight}{#1\quad}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[choices]{label*={\Alph*)},labelindent=1.375em,leftmargin=*,align=straight}
\newcommand{\choice}{\item}

\makeatletter
        \newlist{@inlinechoices}{enumerate*}{1}
        \setlist[@inlinechoices]{label*={\Alph*)},itemjoin={\qquad},align=straight}
        \newenvironment{inlinechoices}{\hspace*{1.375em}\begin{@inlinechoices}}{\end{@inlinechoices}}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

 Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla

\begin{choices}
    \choice $\dfrac{4}{7}$
    \choice $\dfrac{8}{24}$\label{824}
    \choice $\dfrac{44}{121}$
    \choice $\dfrac{9}{11}$
\end{choices}

 Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla As in \ref{824}
\bigskip

\begin{inlinechoices}
    \choice $\dfrac{4}{7}$
    \choice $\dfrac{8}{24}$
    \choice $\dfrac{44}{121}$\label{44}
    \choice $\dfrac{9}{11}$
\end{inlinechoices}
\bigskip

\noindent Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla As in \ref{44}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `straight` astuce ;-) , and also for `labelindent=1.375em,leftmargin=*`.